# Thermodynamics: Calculate heat flow

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, entropy

I was given the following scheme of a power plant:

$
{\def\place#1#2#3{\smash{\rlap{\hskip{#1px}\raise{#2px}{#3}}}}}
%
\place{300}{290}{\begin{array}{c} 60 \, \mathrm{bar} \\ 575\sideset{^{\circ}}{}{\mathrm{C}} \end{array}}
\place{342}{107}{60\sideset{^{\circ}}{}{\mathrm{C}}}
\place{550}{100}{0.05\,\mathrm{bar}}
$[image]

### Given information:

- $p_2 = 60 \, \mathrm{bar}$, $t_2 = 575 °\mathrm{C}$
- $(P_t)_{23}=0.8 \, \mathrm{MW}$
- $(P_t)_{34}=0.2 \, \mathrm{MW}$
- $p_4=0.05 \, \mathrm{bar}$
- $t_5 = 60°\mathrm{C}$
- the turbines and pumps are adiabatic and frictionless
- the condensator is isobaric
- the mixer is adiabtic

My task was to calculate the heat flow $\dot{Q}_H.$

I started with the following:

$$\dfrac{dU}{d\tau} = 0 = \dot{m_{in}} \cdot h_{in} - \dot{m_{out}} \cdot h_{out} - \dot{Q_H}$$
$$\dot{Q_H} = \dot{m}\cdot(h_{in} - h_{out})$$

and:

$$\dfrac{dS}{d\tau} = 0 = \dot{m_{in}} \cdot s_{in} - \dot{m_{out}} \cdot s_{out} - \dfrac{\dot{Q_H}}{T_{m}}$$
$$\dfrac{\dot{Q_H}}{T_{m}} = \dot{m}\cdot(s_{in} - s_{out})$$

this concludes that:
$$T_m=\dfrac{h_{in} - h_{out}}{s_{in} - s_{out}}$$

After that, I am totally stuck.

Now my problem is that I nearly have no information given. From the previous task I calculated that $\dot{m}_2 = 0.96461 \, \mathrm{kg}/\mathrm{s}$.

I am not allowed to make the assumption that I am dealing with an ideal gas.
What I do know however is that I got only gas in $3$ and only liquid in $5$.

Now I need to know how I could calculate $\dot{Q_H}$.

Comment: What you've done so far is not correct.  You need to use the steam tables to solve this.  Have you heard of the steam tables?  Do they tell you the mass flow rate, or do you have to solve for that?  What is the state of stream 2 (saturated or superheated)?  This is the stream that you start with.

Comment: Yeah I do have those tables.I do not have the flow rate given allthough i calculated the flowrate of stream 2. Its described in the question :)

Comment: Also 2 is overheating, and 3 is saturated

Comment: Ya know, one thing I never really understood is why many authors insist on drawing process flow diagrams in such a hideous way.

Comment: RWTH ^^ I assume they know what they do

Comment: OK.  From your steam tables, what is the entropy per unit mass and the enthalpy per unit mass in state 2?  What is the entropy per unit mass for state 3, given that the 2-3 compression takes place adiabatically and reversibly?  What are the temperature, pressure, and enthalpy per unit mass for state 3?

Comment: okay i got the data in point 3. what now?

Comment: From the open system version of the first law of thermodynamics for steady flow, how are the mass flow rate through turbine 2-3, the power produced by turbine 2-3, and the enthalpy change per unit mass through adiabatic turbine 2-3 related?  From this relationship, what is the mass flow rate through turbine 2-3?

Comment: It is $\dot{m}_2 = 0.96461 kg/s$

Comment: Please answer my question in my previous comment.  Is this value for the mass flow rate consistent with what you would calculate using the method I alluded to?